# Model fitting: From "nlmer" to "nlme"

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

How can I fit the following model BUT using "nlme" instead "nlmer"?

The data (at the end of the post, you can find the data to reproduce the code written here).

```
dd.gr <- groupedData(y ~ x | id, dd)
```

Define some functions

```
beta.model <- function(cl, b0, b1, b2) {
    f <- b0*(cl^b1)*(1-cl)^b2
    return(f)}

nform <- ~ b0*(cl^b1)*(1-cl)^b2
nfun <- deriv(nform, namevec=c("b0", "b1", "b2"),
              function.arg=c("cl","b0", "b1", "b2"))
```

Generate start parameters

```
start.dd <- nls(y ~ beta.model(x, b0, b1, b2),
                 start=list(b0=1, b1=1, b2=1),
                 data=dd.gr)
start.dd <- coef(start.dd)
```

Fit the nonlinear model

```
fit <- lme4::nlmer(y ~ nfun(x, b0, b1, b2) ~
                 (b0|id),
             data = dd.gr,
             start = start.dd, REML=T)
summary(fit)

Nonlinear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['nlmerMod']
Formula: y ~ nfun(x, b0, b1, b2) ~ (b0 | id)
   Data: dd.gr

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 -1673.5  -1652.0    841.7  -1683.5      534 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4812 -0.6319  0.0865  0.5712  3.2816 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name Variance Std.Dev.
 id       b0   0.03537  0.18808 
 Residual      0.00221  0.04701 
Number of obs: 539, groups:  id, 20

Fixed effects:
   Estimate Std. Error t value
b0  0.99075    0.04902   20.21
b1  0.45828    0.01449   31.62
b2  0.65220    0.01734   37.60

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   b0    b1   
b1 0.480      
b2 0.475 0.809
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me adapt my code for what I propose.

---

Here the data "dd":

```
y        x   id
1   0.19012041 0.033511   20
2   0.28284850 0.068081   20
3   0.30852905 0.101623   20
4   0.33527818 0.137577   20
5   0.38641197 0.170015   20
6   0.41929523 0.207414   20
7   0.41697570 0.240817   20
8   0.41720256 0.274229   20
9   0.42971583 0.311311   20
10  0.41991537 0.345469   20
11  0.43032094 0.377397   20
12  0.43643438 0.414996   20
13  0.42266673 0.446316   20
14  0.43037591 0.480386   20
15  0.41315721 0.516730   20
16  0.40941867 0.550281   20
17  0.38272123 0.586440   20
18  0.38690141 0.619709   20
19  0.37053631 0.655532   20
20  0.35475040 0.690939   20
21  0.33294172 0.722318   20
22  0.26763630 0.754480   20
23  0.21367107 0.793380   20
24  0.19283832 0.826003   20
25  0.18314927 0.862719   20
26  0.16607962 0.895078   20
27  0.10271515 0.929464   20
28  0.05054509 0.964828   20
29  0.12439211 0.055681   29
30  0.24075680 0.113468   29
31  0.28940082 0.165547   29
32  0.36451986 0.222673   29
33  0.39986469 0.279548   29
34  0.41949874 0.338177   29
35  0.42081401 0.387903   29
36  0.41949874 0.446316   29
37  0.41166800 0.500000   29
38  0.39383040 0.556794   29
39  0.35305355 0.613815   29
40  0.31752589 0.670729   29
41  0.28620056 0.722318   29
42  0.24354607 0.779668   29
43  0.21800329 0.837162   29
44  0.18740906 0.888411   29
45  0.16769700 0.946148   29
46  0.35212840 0.040750 1970
47  0.48320028 0.085903 1970
48  0.53451401 0.126127 1970
49  0.55424578 0.165547 1970
50  0.56271842 0.207414 1970
51  0.57498323 0.252096 1970
52  0.57982842 0.291917 1970
53  0.57911318 0.331517 1970
54  0.54955214 0.370496 1970
55  0.54106483 0.414996 1970
56  0.51983827 0.459525 1970
57  0.48683208 0.505156 1970
58  0.41197552 0.543154 1970
59  0.39301102 0.581372 1970
60  0.35144113 0.624610 1970
61  0.32615887 0.670729 1970
62  0.30356154 0.709662 1970
63  0.25400500 0.749612 1970
64  0.23843431 0.788056 1970
65  0.17314649 0.832348 1970
66  0.11181707 0.876633 1970
67  0.09217675 0.914606 1970
68  0.05513091 0.955580 1970
69  0.27973694 0.033511 1971
70  0.31497877 0.068081 1971
71  0.31774541 0.101623 1971
72  0.33633484 0.137577 1971
73  0.38142103 0.170015 1971
74  0.39212430 0.207414 1971
75  0.41776918 0.240817 1971
76  0.46544395 0.274229 1971
77  0.48094132 0.311311 1971
78  0.47609669 0.345469 1971
79  0.48437211 0.377397 1971
80  0.49303656 0.414996 1971
81  0.51532308 0.446316 1971
82  0.52591006 0.480386 1971
83  0.53168086 0.516730 1971
84  0.53575850 0.550281 1971
85  0.53642039 0.586440 1971
86  0.53831331 0.619709 1971
87  0.49989785 0.655532 1971
88  0.47896984 0.690939 1971
89  0.44155355 0.722318 1971
90  0.39668264 0.754480 1971
91  0.36687930 0.793380 1971
92  0.28175916 0.826003 1971
93  0.25477636 0.862719 1971
94  0.20772056 0.895078 1971
95  0.18146242 0.929464 1971
96  0.11509623 0.964828 1971
97  0.29424805 0.028771 2037
98  0.31100689 0.055681 2037
99  0.37968128 0.080921 2037
100 0.44570510 0.113468 2037
101 0.47689253 0.132828 2037
102 0.51388355 0.165547 2037
103 0.52951039 0.190470 2037
104 0.53486242 0.214077 2037
105 0.55310811 0.249102 2037
106 0.54069923 0.274229 2037
107 0.56085704 0.298996 2037
108 0.57346329 0.331517 2037
109 0.57252492 0.349985 2037
110 0.55666983 0.377397 2037
111 0.55588612 0.408420 2037
112 0.53516121 0.434682 2037
113 0.53464502 0.459525 2037
114 0.51990000 0.497546 2037
115 0.51118999 0.505156 2037
116 0.50976662 0.543154 2037
117 0.51704108 0.567886 2037
118 0.51518273 0.592719 2037
119 0.51144578 0.624610 2037
120 0.48702363 0.651879 2037
121 0.46874780 0.670729 2037
122 0.46610520 0.702626 2037
123 0.45957450 0.729257 2037
124 0.44940666 0.754480 2037
125 0.41248172 0.788056 2037
126 0.39988825 0.811593 2037
127 0.38568122 0.837162 2037
128 0.34338463 0.862719 2037
129 0.28846227 0.888411 2037
130 0.18329780 0.921480 2037
131 0.14774007 0.946148 2037
132 0.08575088 0.972091 2037
133 0.21763661 0.028771 2038
134 0.23256787 0.062335 2038
135 0.31054960 0.094141 2038
136 0.33781744 0.126127 2038
137 0.33712660 0.159287 2038
138 0.35776009 0.190470 2038
139 0.36132643 0.222673 2038
140 0.37726677 0.249102 2038
141 0.38080348 0.279548 2038
142 0.38177161 0.311311 2038
143 0.36956664 0.338177 2038
144 0.36977686 0.377397 2038
145 0.37166348 0.408420 2038
146 0.37411226 0.434682 2038
147 0.36272173 0.470750 2038
148 0.35090634 0.500000 2038
149 0.34812706 0.530893 2038
150 0.33913760 0.561354 2038
151 0.33184098 0.592719 2038
152 0.31086225 0.624610 2038
153 0.30179281 0.655532 2038
154 0.29244225 0.685227 2038
155 0.29171056 0.715608 2038
156 0.28896703 0.749612 2038
157 0.27356355 0.779668 2038
158 0.24517447 0.811593 2038
159 0.24808910 0.843440 2038
160 0.24206431 0.876633 2038
161 0.17025486 0.907147 2038
162 0.08859430 0.939046 2038
163 0.01079669 0.967649 2038
164 0.17164772 0.055681 2167
165 0.20956873 0.118653 2167
166 0.25329354 0.176730 2167
167 0.31110630 0.234884 2167
168 0.34389648 0.291917 2167
169 0.36050986 0.349985 2167
170 0.35936234 0.414996 2167
171 0.36918899 0.470750 2167
172 0.35897902 0.530893 2167
173 0.36581733 0.586440 2167
174 0.36862919 0.646015 2167
175 0.33702190 0.709662 2167
176 0.31287146 0.761244 2167
177 0.24696364 0.826003 2167
178 0.23022979 0.883711 2167
179 0.21250447 0.939046 2167
180 0.17598238 0.033511 2170
181 0.18737701 0.062335 2170
182 0.25275592 0.094141 2170
183 0.28559558 0.126127 2170
184 0.32734108 0.159287 2170
185 0.34818007 0.197259 2170
186 0.36637420 0.222673 2170
187 0.37547146 0.259716 2170
188 0.37475402 0.291917 2170
189 0.38964924 0.322916 2170
190 0.41576375 0.355376 2170
191 0.42667442 0.387903 2170
192 0.44626303 0.421442 2170
193 0.45753246 0.452095 2170
194 0.47906100 0.484540 2170
195 0.48635176 0.516730 2170
196 0.48690479 0.550281 2170
197 0.47611344 0.581372 2170
198 0.46409143 0.613815 2170
199 0.44356431 0.646015 2170
200 0.43274461 0.678666 2170
201 0.42292197 0.709662 2170
202 0.37036428 0.741452 2170
203 0.34960413 0.773048 2170
204 0.32294790 0.805637 2170
205 0.26755673 0.837162 2170
206 0.24912608 0.868745 2170
207 0.19643837 0.901224 2170
208 0.16754568 0.934460 2170
209 0.16021908 0.967649 2170
210 0.02224721 0.028771 2779
211 0.11104242 0.046814 2779
212 0.16841056 0.074093 2779
213 0.18409920 0.094141 2779
214 0.19098377 0.118653 2779
215 0.19968678 0.143437 2779
216 0.24379425 0.165547 2779
217 0.26619965 0.184325 2779
218 0.29353416 0.214077 2779
219 0.31359542 0.234884 2779
220 0.30777733 0.252096 2779
221 0.33962059 0.279548 2779
222 0.34543186 0.306186 2779
223 0.35301113 0.331517 2779
224 0.36405476 0.349985 2779
225 0.37258480 0.370496 2779
226 0.38418643 0.395798 2779
227 0.39501225 0.414996 2779
228 0.40087943 0.446316 2779
229 0.40893103 0.465443 2779
230 0.38764362 0.497546 2779
231 0.37029641 0.505156 2779
232 0.36884072 0.537179 2779
233 0.35422820 0.556794 2779
234 0.34543186 0.581372 2779
235 0.32837782 0.606240 2779
236 0.33608560 0.632230 2779
237 0.33095619 0.651879 2779
238 0.31397261 0.670729 2779
239 0.31170265 0.697418 2779
240 0.28869241 0.722318 2779
241 0.27357500 0.749612 2779
242 0.25919586 0.767440 2779
243 0.24564087 0.788056 2779
244 0.21054514 0.818738 2779
245 0.18037964 0.837162 2779
246 0.15573046 0.857893 2779
247 0.14260262 0.883711 2779
248 0.09563263 0.907147 2779
249 0.08206988 0.929464 2779
250 0.03908776 0.955580 2779
251 0.02125794 0.972091 2779
252 0.33096335 0.037328 2780
253 0.36969011 0.074093 2780
254 0.44504021 0.113468 2780
255 0.45485124 0.151987 2780
256 0.46464513 0.190470 2780
257 0.53736638 0.229281 2780
258 0.57555094 0.267528 2780
259 0.59723195 0.306186 2780
260 0.61552894 0.345469 2780
261 0.62033914 0.383389 2780
262 0.61015052 0.421442 2780
263 0.59728123 0.459525 2780
264 0.59515874 0.497546 2780
265 0.55152852 0.537179 2780
266 0.52641099 0.574251 2780
267 0.48956528 0.613815 2780
268 0.48497512 0.651879 2780
269 0.45698140 0.690939 2780
270 0.43844469 0.729257 2780
271 0.41683569 0.767440 2780
272 0.40151589 0.805637 2780
273 0.39202175 0.843440 2780
274 0.38459441 0.883711 2780
275 0.28157268 0.921480 2780
276 0.21164063 0.960888 2780
277 0.08489932 0.028771 1771
278 0.12305442 0.055681 1771
279 0.14546015 0.080921 1771
280 0.20507495 0.106794 1771
281 0.21327282 0.132828 1771
282 0.22885254 0.165547 1771
283 0.25315275 0.190470 1771
284 0.28460782 0.214077 1771
285 0.28404561 0.249102 1771
286 0.29963138 0.274229 1771
287 0.30334288 0.298996 1771
288 0.32026109 0.331517 1771
289 0.37167406 0.349985 1771
290 0.39620088 0.377397 1771
291 0.41163531 0.408420 1771
292 0.41672284 0.434682 1771
293 0.43135634 0.459525 1771
294 0.43591399 0.497546 1771
295 0.44049046 0.505156 1771
296 0.43976407 0.543154 1771
297 0.42582959 0.567886 1771
298 0.41946869 0.592719 1771
299 0.40894347 0.624610 1771
300 0.40408173 0.651879 1771
301 0.39886942 0.670729 1771
302 0.36607992 0.702626 1771
303 0.35079531 0.729257 1771
304 0.33792425 0.754480 1771
305 0.31231247 0.788056 1771
306 0.29062044 0.811593 1771
307 0.27997472 0.837162 1771
308 0.23381520 0.868745 1771
309 0.20789011 0.888411 1771
310 0.20415166 0.921480 1771
311 0.10956034 0.946148 1771
312 0.07090901 0.972091 1771
313 0.25314656 0.046814 1773
314 0.30329515 0.085903 1773
315 0.32123976 0.132828 1773
316 0.34022917 0.176730 1773
317 0.36301058 0.214077 1773
318 0.37100331 0.259716 1773
319 0.38405288 0.306186 1773
320 0.40362816 0.349985 1773
321 0.41329562 0.395798 1773
322 0.44000388 0.434682 1773
323 0.44340953 0.480386 1773
324 0.44170999 0.521847 1773
325 0.44880483 0.567886 1773
326 0.44754614 0.606240 1773
327 0.43829113 0.651879 1773
328 0.43014986 0.697418 1773
329 0.40816814 0.741452 1773
330 0.41000674 0.779668 1773
331 0.40465177 0.826003 1773
332 0.34777252 0.868745 1773
333 0.32310745 0.914606 1773
334 0.18171237 0.955580 1773
335 0.26951496 0.040750 2001
336 0.37914212 0.080921 2001
337 0.40401647 0.118653 2001
338 0.42272825 0.159287 2001
339 0.43048811 0.197259 2001
340 0.46236016 0.240817 2001
341 0.50902284 0.279548 2001
342 0.52259916 0.318519 2001
343 0.53243477 0.361549 2001
344 0.54973030 0.400000 2001
345 0.53761080 0.439565 2001
346 0.51653397 0.480386 2001
347 0.49107186 0.521847 2001
348 0.44538828 0.561354 2001
349 0.43004423 0.600000 2001
350 0.42084156 0.641002 2001
351 0.42922927 0.678666 2001
352 0.41879440 0.722318 2001
353 0.32868583 0.761244 2001
354 0.29564826 0.800000 2001
355 0.23628702 0.843440 2001
356 0.20310825 0.876633 2001
357 0.13773623 0.921480 2001
358 0.12074184 0.960888 2001
359 0.39968960 0.046814 2003
360 0.57863824 0.101623 2003
361 0.65666614 0.151987 2003
362 0.67908133 0.197259 2003
363 0.67341823 0.249102 2003
364 0.65522550 0.298996 2003
365 0.64079619 0.349985 2003
366 0.64435662 0.395798 2003
367 0.63861925 0.452095 2003
368 0.63588759 0.500000 2003
369 0.61311017 0.550281 2003
370 0.62738351 0.606240 2003
371 0.61852138 0.651879 2003
372 0.58223709 0.697418 2003
373 0.54161098 0.749612 2003
374 0.48646018 0.805637 2003
375 0.38459670 0.851205 2003
376 0.38043597 0.901224 2003
377 0.27075957 0.946148 2003
378 0.38036247 0.037328 2122
379 0.40276000 0.074093 2122
380 0.39612914 0.113468 2122
381 0.42791423 0.151987 2122
382 0.42825796 0.190470 2122
383 0.46095690 0.229281 2122
384 0.48521779 0.267528 2122
385 0.49731865 0.306186 2122
386 0.54605868 0.345469 2122
387 0.54933640 0.383389 2122
388 0.55525115 0.421442 2122
389 0.55625728 0.459525 2122
390 0.55072754 0.497546 2122
391 0.55657463 0.537179 2122
392 0.53676362 0.574251 2122
393 0.50652415 0.613815 2122
394 0.48860251 0.651879 2122
395 0.47683604 0.690939 2122
396 0.44212102 0.729257 2122
397 0.39612914 0.767440 2122
398 0.38528248 0.805637 2122
399 0.34693920 0.843440 2122
400 0.29693585 0.883711 2122
401 0.26873795 0.921480 2122
402 0.22797492 0.960888 2122
403 0.24762581 0.033511 2125
404 0.29675779 0.062335 2125
405 0.32531104 0.094141 2125
406 0.33472047 0.126127 2125
407 0.34663074 0.159287 2125
408 0.35390041 0.197259 2125
409 0.36387951 0.222673 2125
410 0.37320407 0.259716 2125
411 0.38901117 0.291917 2125
412 0.39308746 0.322916 2125
413 0.40142535 0.355376 2125
414 0.41491642 0.387903 2125
415 0.42316665 0.421442 2125
416 0.41814693 0.452095 2125
417 0.40435419 0.484540 2125
418 0.37175904 0.516730 2125
419 0.38099944 0.550281 2125
420 0.38516053 0.581372 2125
421 0.37985668 0.613815 2125
422 0.37717678 0.646015 2125
423 0.30406241 0.678666 2125
424 0.34248509 0.709662 2125
425 0.32696141 0.741452 2125
426 0.29019762 0.773048 2125
427 0.28639182 0.805637 2125
428 0.16112100 0.837162 2125
429 0.15240521 0.868745 2125
430 0.14023783 0.901224 2125
431 0.11144973 0.934460 2125
432 0.04684425 0.967649 2125
433 0.12738818 0.033511 3355
434 0.12032137 0.068081 3355
435 0.19246996 0.101623 3355
436 0.30021305 0.137577 3355
437 0.39536852 0.170015 3355
438 0.43191219 0.207414 3355
439 0.45271647 0.240817 3355
440 0.47445420 0.274229 3355
441 0.48947320 0.311311 3355
442 0.51200729 0.345469 3355
443 0.51159131 0.377397 3355
444 0.50573160 0.414996 3355
445 0.50671293 0.446316 3355
446 0.49885571 0.480386 3355
447 0.47911798 0.516730 3355
448 0.48398125 0.550281 3355
449 0.45930461 0.586440 3355
450 0.44893852 0.619709 3355
451 0.42866861 0.655532 3355
452 0.40953422 0.690939 3355
453 0.37415759 0.722318 3355
454 0.34808624 0.754480 3355
455 0.34998393 0.793380 3355
456 0.31834044 0.826003 3355
457 0.24694972 0.862719 3355
458 0.22192562 0.895078 3355
459 0.17830631 0.929464 3355
460 0.17509332 0.964828 3355
461 0.23328477 0.046814 3356
462 0.29713891 0.094141 3356
463 0.33913003 0.137577 3356
464 0.39302555 0.184325 3356
465 0.42662490 0.229281 3356
466 0.45006759 0.274229 3356
467 0.45955706 0.318519 3356
468 0.46964286 0.361549 3356
469 0.47564354 0.408420 3356
470 0.47304390 0.452095 3356
471 0.44970213 0.500000 3356
472 0.42720259 0.543154 3356
473 0.41737157 0.592719 3356
474 0.39780731 0.632230 3356
475 0.35407259 0.685227 3356
476 0.30057734 0.729257 3356
477 0.20794585 0.773048 3356
478 0.20253853 0.818738 3356
479 0.16693878 0.862719 3356
480 0.08553668 0.907147 3356
481 0.03007141 0.955580 3356
482 0.12522795 0.037328 2873
483 0.12723816 0.074093 2873
484 0.14477616 0.106794 2873
485 0.15411502 0.143437 2873
486 0.21348148 0.176730 2873
487 0.26271901 0.214077 2873
488 0.27856451 0.252096 2873
489 0.31723668 0.285536 2873
490 0.34120764 0.318519 2873
491 0.36044750 0.355376 2873
492 0.36332243 0.395798 2873
493 0.36755816 0.428268 2873
494 0.37460158 0.465443 2873
495 0.38178095 0.500000 2873
496 0.38118229 0.537179 2873
497 0.36989800 0.574251 2873
498 0.35641212 0.606240 2873
499 0.33814474 0.641002 2873
500 0.30921638 0.678666 2873
501 0.28200482 0.715608 2873
502 0.26425989 0.754480 2873
503 0.25337707 0.788056 2873
504 0.24647287 0.818738 2873
505 0.22176036 0.857893 2873
506 0.16676785 0.895078 2873
507 0.11398351 0.929464 2873
508 0.05037407 0.964828 2873
509 0.27228222 0.028771 2874
510 0.34193313 0.062335 2874
511 0.39443653 0.094141 2874
512 0.42802678 0.126127 2874
513 0.43522858 0.159287 2874
514 0.43105717 0.190470 2874
515 0.44967499 0.222673 2874
516 0.46696994 0.249102 2874
517 0.47057562 0.279548 2874
518 0.47811186 0.311311 2874
519 0.47603496 0.338177 2874
520 0.47778667 0.377397 2874
521 0.48030114 0.408420 2874
522 0.48376732 0.434682 2874
523 0.47758331 0.470750 2874
524 0.47316947 0.500000 2874
525 0.46672024 0.530893 2874
526 0.47349784 0.561354 2874
527 0.45448816 0.592719 2874
528 0.44419784 0.624610 2874
529 0.43478196 0.655532 2874
530 0.36181003 0.685227 2874
531 0.37885981 0.715608 2874
532 0.38476236 0.749612 2874
533 0.36972431 0.779668 2874
534 0.34385953 0.811593 2874
535 0.24493663 0.843440 2874
536 0.24109927 0.876633 2874
537 0.21870520 0.907147 2874
538 0.19573503 0.939046 2874
539 0.19263348 0.967649 2874
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fit2 <- nlme::nlme(y ~ nfun(x, b0, b1, b2),
                   data = dd.gr,
                   fixed = b0 + b1 + b2 ~ 1,
                   random = b0 ~ 1 | id,
                   start = start.dd,
                   method = "REML")
```